# How to have parameters in property keys in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

According to [Parameters - Neo4j Cypher Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), this is not allowed

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something'
```

I wonder if there is a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called 'square bracket syntax' and mentioned here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/operators/#syntax-accessing-dynamic-map-parameter

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n[$param] = 'something'
```